# C# и PostgreSQL. Разработка под WinXP

Tags: c#, postgresql

Какой более свежий PostgreSQL и библиотека Npgsql для него, которые могли бы работать и на WinXP SP2 с Net Framework 2.0 и на Win7,8,10?
или как поступить в таком случае?

Comment: `как поступить в таком случае?` - забыть про древнюю WinXP?)

Comment: ябсрадостью) но это не мои прихоти(

Comment: А сервер базы вы тоже планируете ставить на это зоопарк или же сервер будет установлен на линукс машине или на отдельной более-менее свежей серверной винде?

Comment: Прошу присесть... Всё намного ужаснее...  несколько компьютеров (те самые XP) находятся на удалении ни как не связанные в одну ЛВС... прям на них будет и БД и программа... а потом... данные будут переносится в другую БД...

Comment: Ну [psqlODBC и psqlJDBC](https://www.postgresql.org/download/products/2-drivers-and-interfaces/) еще ни кто не отменил. Для XP должно работать. А по поводу красивой .net обертки - что-то сомнительно...

Comment: "а потом... данные будут переносится в другую БД..." с помощью флешки небось? Похоже на какую-то гос.контору не иначе...

Comment: Шерлок?!)  Проблема собственно в том, что не хочется при увеличении функционала программы собирать отдельно под одну и другую машину с изменением настроек проекта или делать 2 или более проекта и потом добавлять/изменять куски кода в каждой...

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно сделать раздельные интерфейсные проекты, а базу размещать на виртуальной Linux-машине, образ которой и копировать.

Comment: это вариант, но прямо говоря выглядит слишком сложно - как из пушки по воробьям. мне кажется, что хотелось бы менее сложный вариант, хотя я и не уверен, что он есть.